# How to keep space in unpopulated column

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml

I have the following XAML code for a Universal app on Windows Phone 8.1:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Image Grid.Column="1" Source="{Binding BarcodeImg}"></Image>
</Grid>
```

I'm trying to have the image take exactly the middle 50% of the screen, but when I run with this code, the left column gets squeezed. How should I achieve this?

Comment: that should work. Are there any other elements in your `Grid` that could affect the spacing? Have you tried `Stretch=UniformToFill` on the image?

Comment: @dellywheel I have not tried Stretch=UniformToFill. Will give it a try today. thanks.

Comment: @dellywheel Stretch=UniformToFill does not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />![example pic ][2]
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Image Grid.Column="1"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               Source="/Assets/allocate.png"
               Stretch="Uniform" />
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate the ![example pic ][2] there? I tried Horizontal/Vertical alignment and that didn't help.